# How do I use a regular expression to remove text in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Need to search a string and replace value="*ANYTHING*" with value="", basically blank out the value. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myString = 'blah value="ANYTHING"';
myString = myString.replace(/value="[^"]+"/, 'value=""');
```

Note that replace does not do anything in-place, so you have to use the returned value.